# How to monitor gradient flow in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I would like to monitor the gradient flow as my models are being trained in Tensorflow 2.0. Ideally, I would like to store the gradients in an array as the model is being trained, and then just view them via matplotlib after training is complete. How would I do this?

Here's a toy model that I would like to run:

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

input_sequence = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[number_timesteps, number_features])
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(2**5, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(input_sequence)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
output_sequence = tf.keras.layers.Dense(number_classes, activation="softmax")(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(input_sequence, output_sequence)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=["accuracy"], optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
model.summary()

model.fit(...)
```

Comment: You can use tensorboard and dump gradient norm https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tensorboard-tutorial

Comment: why do I have to use tensorboard to get the gradients? Why can't I get them directly?